# run time error using sort function

Tags: c++

The problem is group all anagrams in a string vector.
I wrote the code for it using sort function in C++, but I got run time error and I don't know what is wrong. Could you please help me with this? Thank you!

My code:

```
 bool  comp(string s1, string s2){
    sort(s1.begin(), s1.end());
    sort(s2.begin(), s2.end());
    return (s1<=s2);
    }
    vector<string> anagrams(vector<string> &strs) {
        if(strs.size()==0 || strs.size()==1) return strs;
        sort(strs.begin(), strs.end(), comp);
    }
```

Comment: Start by running the program in a debugger, so you know where the program crashes.

Comment: And if you actually want an answer, you should post the error message, not 'I get an error'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The comparator should return `true` if first argument is "less" (i.e. comes before) the second. `<=` isn't right, use `<`.

Comment: You need *strict weak ordering*, i.e. use `return (s1 < s2);`

Comment: @jrok That wouldn't cause an error, just an improper sort.

Comment: @aruisdante Aye captain, that's why I posted as comment, not as an answer :)

Comment: < is still not working.

Comment: You have *undefined behaviour* because you don't always return something from `anagrams`.

Comment: The error message is only "Run time error"

Comment: Before I post my question, I actually tried to debug it by printing s1 and s2 inside comp() function. It seems it compares forever for all strings.

Comment: @aruisdante: An invalid ordering function actually can cause `std::sort` to segfault. Depending on the implementation it can cause the algorithm to walk off the end of the container. I've seen it happen.

Answer (score 1):

When the size of the vector argument to `anagrams` is greater than 1 you don't return anything from the function even though the it's declared to return a vector.

That's undefined behaviour and likely the reason for the crash.

You don't need to return anything from the function as you're sorting the input.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there shall be `s1 < s2` instead of `s1 <= s2` in function comp

```
bool  comp(string s1, string s2){
    sort(s1.begin(), s1.end());
    sort(s2.begin(), s2.end());
    return (s1 < s2);
    }
```

Function anagrams should be defined as

```
void anagrams(vector<string> &strs) {
    sort(strs.begin(), strs.end(), comp);
}
```